# Android: I have a list of contact names, how to get their corresponding emails and pohone numbers?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have an activity that has a listview which displays all contacts with multi-selection enabled. I have also a filter to filter the display result.

After struggling with this problem for 3 days, I finally could produce a list of all display names selected by the user.

My question now is how to get the corresponding email and phone number for each display name in my list?

Update:
I found a solution..

```
    public String getNumber(String name,Context context){

    String number="";

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor people = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

    people.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String Name   = people.getString(indexName);
        String Number = people.getString(indexNumber);
        if(Name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){return Number.replace("-", "");}
        // Do work...
    } while (people.moveToNext());


    if(!number.equalsIgnoreCase("")){return number.replace("-", "");}
    else return number;
}

public String getEmail(String name,Context context){

    String email="";

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};

    Cursor people = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

    people.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String Name   = people.getString(indexName);
        String mail = people.getString(indexNumber);
        if(Name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){return mail;}
        // Do work...
    } while (people.moveToNext());


    if(!email.equalsIgnoreCase("")){return email;}
    else return email;
}
```

Got it from there:
[Android get contact number using name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188028/android-get-contact-number-using-name)

Comment: `"My question now is how to get the corresponding email and phone number for each display name in my list?"` Where are these stored?

Comment: My listview has all display names in the phonebook. I have List<String> contactNames that has all selected contact names. I want to get their corresponding e-mails and phone numbers stored in the phone book.

Comment: You can use an ArrayAdapter to accomplish this. That way you can modify and personalise the listview and listitems. Here's a good tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html